# Does any scripture contain details about the life of Samvarta?

Tags: scripture, parashurama, tripura-rahasyam, samvarta

Brihaspathi is well-known as a guru of gods. He has a brother named Samvarta, who is an avaduta. The [following lines](https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Tripura-Rahasya-The-Mystery-Beyond-the-Trinity.pdf#page=14) are taken from the *Introductory Note* of the scripture named Tripura Rahasyam

> Parasurama returned crest-fallen and on his way met an **Avadhuta
> named Samvarta, the brother of Brihaspati.** Later he encountered Sri
> Dattatreya who instructed him in the Truth and so led him to
> salvation.

Parasurama accidentally encountered Samvarta and the contact led Parasurama to vicharana and then enlightenment. The following are the words of Dattatreya to Parashurama

> Association with the Sages is alone said to lead to the highest good.
> **Your contact with Samvarta has led you to this stage of enlightenment**,
> which is the forerunner of emancipation. On being approached, the
> Sages teach the greatest good.
>
> [[8-9, 3, Jnana Kanda, Tripura Rahasyam]](https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Tripura-Rahasya-The-Mystery-Beyond-the-Trinity.pdf#page=38)

I don't think the Tripura Rahasya contains the history of Samvarta. I am interested in knowing his childhood, how he became avaduta etc.,

Does any scripture contain details pertaining to the life of Samvarta?

Comment: Kindly refer to Ashwamedha Yajna Parva of Mahabharata.

Comment: Do you know any particular chapter form [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/index.htm) @Chamundadas

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241921.html   got the better list of all chapters in one place.